# SQL Server 2016 Import and Export: A column named 'SQL_NO_NULLS' already belongs to this table

Tags: sql-server, database, odbc, filemaker, wizard

I want to copy data with SQL Server 2016 Import and Export data (wizard) from a FileMaker database to a SQL Server 2016 db (using ODBC).

I get the error 'A column named 'SQL_NO_NULLS' already belongs to this table' when I proceed after selecting the tables or when I try to change the mappings.

It doesn't matter if I select only one table or several. But if I query a single table, there is no problem.

Problem happens on both 32bit and 64bit ODBC connection/wizard.

[image]

Comment: The import/export "wizard" is flakey at the best of time. You're honestly better off making the SSIS package manually half the time.

Comment: How do I do that? In visual studio? Could I also use sqlcmd? My goal is to copy the filemaker db daily and then make queries on the copy (for reporting).